# PHP Traits: How to resolve a property name conflict?

Tags: php, oop, traits

How to resolve a property name conflict when a class uses two Traits with **homonymous properties**?

Example:

```
<?php

trait Video {
    public $name = 'v';
}


trait Audio {

    public $name = 'a';
}


class Media {
    use Audio, Video;
}

$media = new Media();
$media->name;
```

I've tried insteadof (*Video::name insteadof Audio*) and (*Video::name as name2*) without success.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't, its for methods only.
However they may use the same property name only if the value is the same:

```
trait Video {
  public $name;
  function getName(){
    return 'Video';
  }
}
trait Audio {
  public $name;
  function getName(){
    return 'Audio';
  }
}
class Media {
  use Audio, Video {
    Video::getName insteadof Audio;
  }

  function __construct(){
    $this->name = $this->getName(); // 'Video'
  }
}
```